# Symfony: translator becomes translator.default in production

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation

I'm using symfony 3.2 and I have a class (a validator for a form which checks if a given e-mail-address is already taken) which is defined as a service and takes 3 arguments which are being injected into it:

```
arguments:
    entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
    translator: '@translator'
    tokenStorage: '@security.token_storage'
```

"translator" is of the type "DataCollectorTranslator".

Now, everything works in development mode, I have checked the created cache-files and found a method (named "getLp_Validator_DuplicateEmailService") which creates the validator with the translator as the second parameter like this:

```
$this->get('translator')
```

In production-mode however, the validator is created with "translator.default" instead of "translator", resulting in the following line in the cached file:

```
$this->get('translator.default')
```

Which (not very suprisingly) leads to the following error:

```
Type error: Argument 2 passed to DuplicateEmailValidator::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\\Component\\Translation\\DataCollectorTranslator, instance of Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Translation\\Translator given
```

Why would symfony make a difference between prod and dev here and how can I stop it from injecting the wrong type of service ot my class?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something that could change the behaviour on dev/prod ? like services.yml !== services_dev.yml ?

Comment: No, the services for the form-validators are defined in a separate validators.yml and the file is the same for dev and prod.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging I ended up fixing this by exchanging "DataCollectorTranslator" with "TranslatorInterface" in the constructor of my validator-class, so both (DataCollectorTranslator and Translator) work, which I don't really consider a fix but rather a workaround.

```
public function __construct(
    EntityManager $entityManager,
    TranslatorInterface $translator,
    TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
) {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->translator    = $translator;
    $this->tokenStorage  = $tokenStorage;
}
```

I'd still be interested, why there's a difference between dev and prod, so if anyone knows the reason, please leave an answer as there's probably other cases where the issue can't be fixed this easily.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I'll add this anyway, as it may be useful.

#### As discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15539):

> In dev, the translator service is decorated with a DataCollectorTranslator to integrate it in the profiler.

And furthermore:

> If you want to typehint the service, use the interface, not the implementation.

Which actually is exactly what was mentioned in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45147015/3105311).